# Percentage of a Volume (includes Basic Summation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is as follows:

> Build a sugar-cube pyramid as follows: First make a 5 × 5 × 1 bottom layer. Then center a 4×4×1 layer on the first layer, center a 3×3×1 layer on the second layer, and center a 2×2×1 layer on the third layer. The fifth layer is a single 1×1×1 cube. Express the volume of this pyramid as a percentage of the volume of a 5 × 5 × 5 cube.

I understand how to find the volume of the sugar-cube pyramid by using summation. 
$$\sum_{x = 1}^5 x^2 = 55$$

What I do not understand is the part that the question says

> Express the volume of this pyramid as a percentage of the volume of a 5 × 5 × 5 cube.

Do they want for me to do $(55\div125) \times 100$ to figure out the percentage?

I understand that this seems like a very basic question to ask, but I really want some clarifications regarding what the question is asking for me to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's what they want you to do.

And the you might try the same thing with a 6x6x6 cube, or a 10x10x10 cube, or a 100x 100 x 100 cube, and see whether the ratio seems to be approaching some particular number.

And when you see that it is, you might further want to ask "How come it approaches *that* number?"

Comment: I got the following percentages for summations with 10, 20, 50, and 100 relative to the numbers being cubed, respectively: 38.5%, 38.875%, 34.34%, 38.835%. I notice the 38% repeating, but the 34.34% for the 50 strikes me as an outlier. Am I doing this right?

Comment: For $100$, you should have gotten $338350 / (100*100*100) = 33.835%$; I think you lost a 3 somewhere. Now the trend is presumably a bit more obvious.

Comment: Also: for $20$, you should have gotten $35.875$, so the sequence is actually $38.5, 35.875, 34.34, 33.835$. For $1001$, you get $33.53%$.